# Winforms databinding and validation, why is datasource updated when validation fails?

Tags: winforms, validation

The code below illustrates some unexpected (for me!) behaviour when combining data binding and validation in winforms. Can anyone tell me how I can prevent the datasource from being updated when validation fails?

Many thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ValidationBug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This illustrates some unexpected behaviour with winforms validation and binding
    /// 
    /// To reproduce: Run the program, enter a value into the textbox, click the X to close the form.
    /// 
    /// Expected behaviour: validation of textbox fails so data source is not updated.
    /// 
    /// Observed behaviour: data source is updated.
    /// </summary>
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private class Data
        {
            private string _field;
            public string Field
            {
                get { return _field; }
                set 
                { 
                    // this should never be called, but it is.
                    _field = value; 
                }
            }
        }

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnablePreventFocusChange;

            var txt = new TextBox();

            // validation always fails.
            txt.Validating += new CancelEventHandler((s, ev) => ev.Cancel = true);
            Controls.Add(txt);

            var data = new Data();

            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(this.components);
            bs.DataSource = typeof(Data);

            // only update datasource on succesful validation.
            txt.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", data, "Field", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation));
        }
    }
}
```