# DataSource gets updated even when Validating is canceled

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, data-binding

Taken right from the C# documentation:

> When you use data binding, the data in your control is synchronized with the data source during execution of the Validating event. If you cancel the Validating event, the data will not be synchronized with the data source.

I am in fact calling:

```
private void textBoxGrainWidth_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int result;
    if(!int.TryParse(textBoxGrainWidth.Text,out result))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

And this in fact calls the setting on the property its bound to via:

```
this.textBoxGrainWidth.DataBindings.Add(
    new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text",
        this.bindingSourceControlData, "GrainWidth", true));
```

So I call BS on the documentation. [This post refers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184431/winforms-databinding-and-validation-why-is-datasource-updated-when-validation-f) to the same problem but with no real solution.

Any advice? Don't use Winforms & Binding & Validation at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have already experienced, if your source is an `int` field and you enter invalid data, it won't be synced. So, I don't know what's the type of your `this.bindingSourceControlData`, but if it isn't an `int`, maybe it should be.